# Openshift: How to access the file that is in the external file system?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am using minishift for deploying my java apllication.

App deployed successfully, but this app need to read/write from some files that are on drive C on my Windows.

I can't just place this files inside container, files should only be in this folder on drive C.

Is there any ways to do it?

Comment: Are you running minishift on the same machine as your C Drive? If so youll want to set up some kind of host file system share. https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/host-folders.html

Comment: @Dylan yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create what is known as host filesystem access/share. More information can be found at the following link https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/host-folders.html